# PHP executing background command line script

Tags: php, shell, command-line, background

Not sure how to word this... but here goes.

I have a php script that I want to run in the background, but I want to call it from another php web page.

This is how I'm trying to call it :

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['go']) && $_REQUEST['go'] =="monitor" ) {
   echo "background script running";
   $cmd = "php -n monitor.php";
   shell_exec("$cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
   exit;
}
```

monitor is quite simple. It logs into a database and checks for a specific value. 
If the value is not found it keeps repeating the process, checking every xx seconds to see if the value has been set.

If it is found it updates a log and exits.

The problem I have is that monitor works fine from the command line, but I can't seem to get it to run when called via another page in the browser.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
   $cmd = "php -n monitor.php";
   shell_exec($cmd);
```

This works but it keeps the page calling it active. As soon as I try to run it in the background it fails.

Any idea why ?

Comment: does monitor.php have read and execute permission for other users?

Comment: have you tried passing the full path? `$cmd = "php -n /var/www/.../monitor.php"`

Comment: @KaranPunamiya monitor has the same permissions as the main page that is calling it.

Comment: @iswinky using the full path doesn't work :(

Comment: What is the permission set to? The other files are called by your user. The monitor.php file is called by www-data.

Comment: @KaranPunamiya All files are 777 and web:public

Comment: original post updated.

Comment: Don't start a process from your webserver. The parent process is not guaranteed to live very long. Compare it with: logging into your server, running this job, and logging out. The child process will have been killed as well if you check after logging back in. You're better of using something like `supervisord`, to which the webserver / PHP can talk, but is not responsible for the process itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following approach

`$command = '/usr/bin/php -n [PATH]/[FILENAME].php >> /tmp/test.log';`

Make sure you have write permission to the log file defined.

Use [**exec**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [**backtick**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) instead of shell_exec.